# Modbus4J 2.0.2 and Maven, How it works?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, modbus

I am using the last version of Modbus4J 2.0.2, converted to use Maven for dependency management. 
In my first Modbus4J project (1 year ago), I only add the different *.jar to my project and it works fine. (modbus4J.jar, seroUtils.jar, RXTXcomm.jar) 
But now I can not do it, if I add the new jar on my project I can see a lot of build errors, regarding for apache libs... 
I am using Eclipse and I installed the maven plugin but I do not know how I can insert the libraries in my project.

Do you know How Can I build and test the files of com.serotonin.modbus4j.test of Modbus4J 2.0.2? (MasterTest.java, ListenerTest.java...) 
And How Can I integrate the new Modbus4J libraries on my project?

The library is here:
https://github.com/infiniteautomation/modbus4j

Thanks in advance,

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [pom.xml file in the modbus4j project](https://github.com/infiniteautomation/modbus4j/blob/master/Modbus4J/pom.xml).  You'll see that it declares a local file based repository (modbus4j-local). That is where the serotonin-timer & serotonin-utils dependencies are stored.

If that doesn't help you, then it's not clear what you are trying to do. Consider posting your project's pom.xml file contents and/or the important build error messages you are seeing.

Comment: Hello @kaliatech, thanks for your help. In the pom.xml I can see the local libraries serotonin-timer & serotonin-utils that I can find in: modbus4j-maven-local. And I can see more libraries, commons-lang3, commons-logging, jssc. Where Can I find these libraries? Must I search in internet? Or Does Maven have these libraries in some directory?     Thanks in advance, best regards.

Comment: When you build a maven project with maven (or using your IDE's maven plugin), it will first download dependencies. By default, it will look in the [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/), &  then will look in any repositories declared in the pom (such as modbus4j-maven-local above).  By default, maven will store the downloaded dependencies in `~/.m2/repository`. Generally though, maven or your IDE takes care of referencing the JAR files from that location automatically.  If for some reason you want a copy of all dependency jars, you can use `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`.

Comment: Hello @kaliatech, thanks for the information. I solved the problem coping the pom.xml libraries from ~/.m2/repository to my project repository. I do not know maven and I do not know how I can use mvn dependency:copy-dependencies. How Can I use this instruction under Eclipse with M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse?